# BI Projects in Visual Studio when SQL Server is in a different machine

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence, reportserver

I've visual studio 2005 installed in one machine (dev machine) and SQL Server 2005 installed in another machine. But only when we install SQL Server with SSRS, we get the Business Intelligence Project templates in Visual Studio.

Now having SQL Server in another machine how can i create a report server project in VS 2005 in the dev machine?

Thank you.

Regards
NLV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can install Bussiness Intelligence Studio without Sql Server. You must run sqlrun_tools.msi file available in

Tools\setup folder of your Sql Server 2005 CD/DVD and then choose client components -> Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Continue through the rest of the installation and you will find a icon under Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

please see this [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1807) too.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Let me check it out.